# simplify javascript array with loop syntax

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript array defined as below:

```
var hexgon = ['M',r*Math.cos(0/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(0/180*Math.PI)                               
                                    ,r*Math.cos(30/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(30/180*Math.PI)
                                    ,r*Math.cos(90/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(90/180*Math.PI)
                                    ,r*Math.cos(150/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(150/180*Math.PI)
                                    ,r*Math.cos(210/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(210/180*Math.PI)
                                    ,r*Math.cos(270/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(270/180*Math.PI),
                                    ,r*Math.cos(330/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(330/180*Math.PI),'Z']
```

How to use a loop to simplify this logic?

Comment: can u find a pattern with 0,30,90,150,210,270,330

Comment: Maybe we can change it to -30,30,90,150,210,270, so +60 each cycle!

Comment: something like this even works without being too complex `['M',...[-30,30,90,150,210,270].flatMap((x) => [r*Math.cos(x/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(x/180*Math.PI)]),'Z']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not intend two commas in a row after the twelth element then this:

```
var hexgon = ['M', ...[0,30,90,150,210,270,330].flatMap(d => [r*Math.cos(d/180*Math.PI),r*Math.sin(d/180*Math.PI)]), 'Z']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can have a constant value as a `step` that gets added to `Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` statements we might be able to do something.

Let's say we want to add `30` each time to the each array's element, we can do something like this: (Also noticed there are `M` and `Z` characters at the beginning and end of your array)

```
const newHexgon = new Array(16);
newHexgon[0] = 'M';
newHexgon[newHexgon.length - 1] = 'Z';
let counter = 0;
let step = 30;
for (let i = 1; i < newHexgon.length - 1; i += 2) {
  newHexgon[i] = Math.cos(((counter * step) / 180) * Math.PI);
  newHexgon[i + 1] = Math.sin(((counter * step) / 180) * Math.PI);
  counter++;
}

console.log(newHexgon);
```

I created an array with a length of 16 and set the first and last elements to "M" and "Z" as in your array. Then I will loop every two elements at a time `i += 2` and set the Math calculations and after finished in each iteration the counter gets added by one.